# Git Exclude Region in Multibranch Pipeline Job Not working

Tags: git, jenkins, github, git-checkout, multibranch-pipeline

I have a GitHub repository and a multi-branch pipeline job. I am trying to exclude some paths from triggering builds, but can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Here are the details.

GitHub URL: https://github.com/my-org/project-name.git

The project has App, DB and Config. DB and Config folders are inside the App. App is at the root level. There are 3 multibranch jobs and 3 Jenkinsfile at the following paths.

project-name/Jenkinsfile 
project-name/db/Jenkinsfile
project-name/config/Jenkinsfile

Requirement is to ensure that a change in a file inside DB directory shouldn't trigger a build for App. PFB the checkout step in the App Jenkinsfile.

```
checkout([
                $class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: "*/${BRANCH_NAME}"]],
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                extensions: [[$class: 'DisableRemotePoll'],[$class: 'PathRestriction', excludedRegions: 'project-name/db/.*', includedRegions: ''],
                    [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: "my-folder-path"]
                ],
                gitTool: "my-git-portable",
                submoduleCfg: [],
                userRemoteConfigs: [
                    [
                        credentialsId: "my-creds",
                        url: "https://github.com/my-org/project-name.git"
                    ]
                ]
            ])
```

I have tried various combinations for excludedRegions like below. I tried generating the above syntax using the Pipeline Syntax with the option "Polling ignores commits in certain paths"

1. project-name/db/.*
2. project-name/db/**/*
3. db/.*
4. db/**/*
5. With and without "includedRegions"
6. With and without DisableRemotePoll (Force Polling using Workspace)

None of the above seems to be working. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a bit old, but in case anyone faces this issue here's the solution I was able to find.

Using the `PathRestriction` plugin seems not to work in multibranch pipelines but the [multibranch-build-strategy-extension](https://plugins.jenkins.io/multibranch-build-strategy-extension/) does the same work.

I found the plugin in a [comment](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-35988?focusedCommentId=368105&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-368105) for the ticket [JENKINS-35988](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-35988)

**DISCLAIMER**: The plugin's latest release was 3 years ago at the time of writing, use at your own risk